# Conditional Apex Call from a LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am quite new to LWC

My component is the following, I have thre picklists options Region, Country, Market so the user select a region then a country then a market and based on that he will be displayed a list of Leads that are part of specific Market.

Now I would like to give the ability to the user to be able to select if he wants to see the list of leads from a Market or a Country.
So I created a checkbox and the expected behaviour would be .. if the checkbox is selected then show me a list of lead related to the market ..

If the check box is not selected then show me a list of all the Lead within the country.

My issue is I do not know how to format my If statement it gives me always an error

```
if('$countryCheckBox' = 1){
        _wiredPropData;
        @wire(propertiesFromMarket, {MarketId: '$selectedMarket'})
        retrieveProperties(wireResult){
            const { data, error } = wireResult;
            this._wiredPropData = wireResult;
            if(data){
                
                this.records = data
                console.log("propData2", this.records)
    
                }
                if(error){
                    console.error(error)
                }
            } else {
                // call the other apex class
            }
    }
```

So if my '$countryCheckBox' = 1 so if the checkbox is selected then .. call one Apex class .. if not .. Call the other Apex class

Could you give me a hand please I get an error

Comment: btw - that syntax above won't work for 2 reasons. 1 - it's a special format that only works in a wire function. 2 - you have an assignment not a comparison (`=` vs `==` or `===`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it would be easier for you to invoke a different method based on the selection within your apex class.

Otherwise, you will have to refactor and [call your Apex methods imperatively](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_call_imperative) based on the condition selected

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than one reactive property in your wire call.

I feel that depending on the data that you are retrieving, you might just want to get all the data and then filter in JavaScript using a map, but that's for you to decide.

Here's a multi-property wire call, with an Apex method that routes to one of two methods based on the supplied params:

```
@wire(getProperties, {marketId: '$selectedMarket', countrySelected: '$countryCheckBox'})
getPropertiesHandler(wireResult){
  const { data, error } = wireResult;
  this._wiredPropData = wireResult;
  if(data){} 
  else {}
  
@AuraEnabled
Properties[] getProperties(String marketId, String countrySelected){
  if (!countrySelected){
    return allProperties(marketId);
  }
  else {
    return propertiesForMarket(marketId);
  }
}
```